# Python super bypass MRO

Tags: python, inheritance, super, method-resolution-order

I have a inherited a class and overwritten a method who also is inherited from a base class. But the thing is that the middle method creates an exception that i would like to bypass by calling the first declared method. Is there a way to specify to the **mro** that ignores the second calls?

An example could be:

```
class Base(object):
     def __init__(self):
         res = "Want this"
         print res

class BaseA(Base):
      def __init__(self):
          res = super(BaseA, self).__init__()
          res = "Not this"
          print res

class BaseB(BaseA):
      def __init__(self):
          res = super(BaseB, self).__init()
          #At this poing res is "Not this"
          #The desire is that it would be "Want this"
          print res
```

Thanks a lot

PD:
Something like class BaseB(Base, BaseA) could work?

Comment: "Something like class BaseB(Base, BaseA) could work?". No, it would raise an exception: `TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    Cannot create a consistent method resolution
order (MRO) for bases Base, BaseA`. In this situations you have to call the specific parent class directly...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Normally** you'd fix that method instead.

However, the first argument to `super()` is the place to start searching for the next method *from*. Normally that'd be the current class, but you can also pass in the base class:

```
class BaseB(BaseA):
    def __init__(self):
        res = super(BaseA, self).__init__()
```

Here, `super()` takes the MRO of `type(self)`, finds `BaseA` in that MRO, and looks for the next class implementing `__init__`.

Another way to bypass the problematic `__init__` method is to just call the unbound method on `Base` directly:

```
class BaseB(BaseA):
    def __init__(self):
        res = Base.__init__(self)
```

bypassing any MRO searches entirely.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked bypassing the super and calling directly the Base class __init__. A simple and effective solution, fantastic. For curiosity purposes i am branching and testing the first fix and see what happens there.

Answer (score 2):

The Right Way to fix this is to create a new class hierarchy which overrides the offending method with an improved implementation. If you insist on hackery though, this may be what you want:

```
class BaseB(BaseA):
      def __init__(self):
          res = super(BaseA, self).__init()
          #At this poing res is "Not this"
          #The desire is that it would be "Want this"
          print res
```

Note that I'm asking for the super implementation with respect to BaseA, which means that the BaseA implementation is never used.

---

However, this *can* do the Wrong Thing when diamond inheritance is involved. Consider:

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print 'initing Base'

class BaseA(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        print 'initing BaseA'
        res = super(BaseA, self).__init__()

class BaseB(BaseA):
    def __init__(self):
        print 'initing BaseB'
        res = super(BaseA, self).__init__()

class BaseC(BaseA):
    def __init__(self):
        print 'initing BaseC'
        res = super(BaseC, self).__init__()

class BaseD(BaseB, BaseC):
    def __init__(self):
        print 'initing BaseD'
        res = super(BaseD, self).__init__()

print BaseD()
```

The output is :

```
initing BaseD
initing BaseB
initing Base
<__main__.BaseD object at 0x7f1e693a0110>
```

`BaseC` was skipped even though that's not what we wanted. This is because `BaseC` came between `BaseB` and `BaseA` in the method resolution order, so when we skipped from `BaseB` to `BaseA` we inadvertently neglected `BaseC`.

```
>>> print [cls.__name__ for cls in BaseD.mro()]
['BaseD', 'BaseB', 'BaseC', 'BaseA', 'Base', 'object']
```

Comment: `super(BaseA, self)` still uses the MRO of `type(self)`, no need to do the calculation yourself here.

Comment: If the type of `self` is `class BaseD(BaseA, BaseB)`, then the above code would produce an infinite loop, no? I'm just trying to note that this isn't so easy in the case of diamond inheritance.

Comment: Python guards against that; you cannot create `class BaseD`: `TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases\n    Cannot create a consistent method resolution\norder (MRO) for bases BaseB, BaseA`

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Today I Learned! While my original example is impossible, the point still holds. I've updated my answer with a demo of the diamond-inheritance edge case.

Answer (score 0):

How bout just

`Base.__init__(self)`